# Flutter Firebase not able to get value outside loop

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using realtime database and trying to fetch some data which I get easily from database but problem is I can't able to get those data outside of the loop below is my code

This is the value avaialbleTimeSlots

```
  var availableTimeSlotsFm1 = [
      "2021-05-08 13:00:00.000",
      "2021-05-08 13:30:00.000",
      "2021-05-08 14:00:00.000",
      "2021-05-08 14:30:00.000",
      "2021-05-08 15:00:00.000",
      "2021-05-08 15:30:00.000",
      "2021-05-08 16:00:00.000",
      "2021-05-08 16:30:00.000",
      "2021-05-08 17:00:00.000",
      "2021-05-08 17:30:00.000"
  ];
```

Now this is how I fetch value from database and remove time from

```
  List providerListd = [
     "2Bauty9IKISrtETSnUaK9uzaon42",
     "P9qtqNACxfT6isDtO5B1ONHpeiy2"
  ];
  final bookedTming = [];
  var output;

  void getBookingTimeSlot() {
      List<dynamic> _bookeFilterdTime = [];

      for (var provider in providerListd) {
         if (provider != null) {
           DatabaseReference providerTripRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
           .reference()
           .child('availableProviderList/${provider}/bookingTime');
           providerTripRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
               var results = [];
               values.forEach((key, values) {
                   var bookingSlot =
                     new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(values['time']);
                   bookedTming.add(bookingSlot.toString());
        
               });

               output = bookedTming
                 .groupListsBy((e) => e)
                 .values
                 .where((e) => e.length > 1)
                 .map((e) => e.first)
                 .toList();

             // This is the value of `output` fetched from database
             // [2021-05-08 13:30:00.000, 2021-05-08 15:30:00.000, 2021-05-08 17:00:00.000]
             // and those needs to be removed from availableTimeSlotsFm1 so if I print 
             // inside it works fine but not outside 

           
                availableTimeSlotsFm1
                   .removeWhere((e) => output.contains(e.toString()));
      
              return output;
     
            });
        }
    } 
 }
```

Expected behaviour is if I print `availableTimeSlotsFm1` then the value should be like this

```
var availableTimeSlotsFm1 = [
   
   "2021-05-08 13:30:00.000",
   "2021-05-08 14:00:00.000",
   "2021-05-08 14:30:00.000",
   
   "2021-05-08 15:30:00.000",
   "2021-05-08 16:00:00.000",
   "2021-05-08 16:30:00.000",
  
   "2021-05-08 17:30:00.000"
];
```

I tried everything but I always get null value of `output` and same value for `availableTimeSlotsFm1`